# GCP firewall rule for tcp port are not working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firewall, google-cloud-networking, google-cloud-instances

I've a VM on which I installed postgres, now I'm trying to connect the this PG from outside, I created a firewall rule that opens the 5432 port to any source IP like below

[image]

My instance has the rule

[image]

But when I try to check if the port is open it fails for me

```
$ nc -zv public-ip 5432
nc: connectx to public-ip port 5432 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
$ nc -zv public-ip 22  
Connection to public-ip port 22 [tcp/ssh] succeeded!
$ psql -h public-ip -p 5432 --username=myuser --dbname=mydb --password 
Password: 
psql: error: connection to server at "public-ip", port 5432 failed: Connection refused
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

I tried restaring the VM but that didn't help. what am I missing?

Comment: If you click into the rule, it should tell you which VMs it currently applies to.  Do you see your PostgreSQL VM listed there?  If you don't, check to make sure you have the right tags on the VM.

Comment: And, in addition to @glen-yu comment, are you confident the VM is exposing the port on a network interface other than localhost/loopback? From the VM (or another VM) can you connect to the database via the VM's internal IP on that port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connection refused means you can initiate a TCP connection but no process is listening on the port, so the connection attempt is refused. This means the firewall is probably not the problem. A firewall problem usually results in a **Timeout** error.

Edit the **postgresql.conf** configuration file:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

[18.3.1. Connection Settings](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/runtime-config-connection.html)

Comment: I also had to add this `host  all  all 0.0.0.0/0 md5` to `pg_hba.conf`